# Vim create and edit new file in the background

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim

I need to create a tmp file from current buffer, edit the new file, yank the result, quit `:q!` and finally paste it back to current buffer. This can be quite useful in cases such as formatting ONLY the visually selected code:

```
 vnoremap <leader>f d:execute "tabnew /tmp/format.".expand("%:e")<cr>p:Autoformat<cr>:%d<cr>:q<cr>P
```

The only annoying thing is that the `:tabnew /tmp/tmp_file`, editing, `:q!`, and paste back sequence is done in the front which has the undesirable side effect of flashing the screen several times in this process. Is there a way to do this process silently in the background?

Comment: If you're using [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat/blob/master/README.md), then `:Autoformat` supports ranges. You can simply use `:Autoformat` from visual mode (will appear as `:'<,'>Autoformat`) and it will only format the lines from the range you visually selected.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has something to do with the formatter `Autoformat` uses. While for languages such as `Python, C/C++` range format works, it fails for `Fortran`.

Comment: I *think* using a split instead of a tab will be better. Can you try using `new` instead of `tabnew` and see if that doesn't blink? It's a very interesting question, I don't have a ready answer for it. You might also want to consider posting questions like this one on [vi.se], you typically have more Vim experts hanging around there so you get more visibility on questions like this one.

Comment: For wide screen, indeed `botright vnew` partially solves the problem. Thanks for your advice!